# How to resize md-dialog-container of angular-material2 based on dropdown component used in dialog content

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2, mddialog

I am using [Angular Material2's dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog) component. Inside dialog, I am using input fields and [angular2-dropdown-multiselect](http://softsimon.github.io/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/).

Now when I open drop down, it adds the scrollbar to the dialog box.

[image]

I want to get dialog should resize automatically rather than providing the scroll bar if I open multi-select dropdown.

I have tried giving max-height property to dialog box, but not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event to your search element:

```
<div class="form-group" (click)="autoScroll($event)">
    <ss-multiselect-dropdown></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
autoScroll(event): void {
  let parent = document.getElementById("ng2Dialog");
  parent.scroll(0, event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top);
}
```

You can change parent with Angular Material2's dialog.

Comment: search is not individual element. It comes with dropdown so i cant change that part

Comment: Do you test click event on "ss-multiselect-dropdow" element? or check this event (ngModelChange)="autoScroll($event)" ?

Comment: Please add the view source code into your question.

Comment: You can wrap "ss-multiselect-dropdown" element with a div and give it a click event. answer updated.